# Apps Script login form inside gmail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I want to create a plugin for Gmail using the Apps Script.
One of the requirements is that I need to login to a 3rd party website which doesn't have Oauth, so I just need a form with 2 fields: username and password and then do an ajax request.

This is my code for the ajax request:

```
var url = "https://domain.example/login.php";
   var options = {
  "method": "post",
  "payload": {
  "email": "info@email.example",
  "password": "password",
  },
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

This works great, but how can I get the username and password from a form?

Comment: It seems that your script is Google Apps Script. From your question, it is found that your script works. When the script is run, you can retrieve the values from ``response``. Can you confirm whether the values you need are included in the ``response``?

Comment: Yes, but I want the user to input the email and password into a form.

Comment: Perhaps, you want to create a form including the text input field using Gmail add-on. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, but there is no password field to hide the password.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added a tag.